# C++: error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '<'

Tags: c++, syntax

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include<vector>

template<class T, int capacity = 30>
class Stack {
public:
    Stack(){
        pool.reserve(capacity);
    }
    void clear(){
        pool.clear;
    }
    void isEmpty(){
        return pool.empty();
    }
    T& topEl(){
        return pool.back();
    }
    T pop(){
        T el = pool.back();
        pool.pop_back();
        return el;
    }
    void push(const T& el){
        pool.push_back(el);
    }
private:
    vector<T> pool;
};


int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    //Stack<int,30> test;
    return 0;
}
```

Above is the code that I have written, which outlines a very generic vector implementation of stack. However,when I compiled it, I got the following errors from the compiler.

```
1>------ Rebuild All started: Project: Stack, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
1>  stdafx.cpp
1>  Stack.cpp
1>c:\users\lxjhk\documents\visual studio 2013\projects\stack\stack\stack.cpp(31): error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '<'
1>          c:\users\lxjhk\documents\visual studio 2013\projects\stack\stack\stack.cpp(32) : see reference to class template instantiation 'Stack<T,capacity>' being compiled
1>c:\users\lxjhk\documents\visual studio 2013\projects\stack\stack\stack.cpp(31): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
1>c:\users\lxjhk\documents\visual studio 2013\projects\stack\stack\stack.cpp(31): error C2238: unexpected token(s) preceding ';'
========== Rebuild All: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 skipped ==========
```

I really could not understand where went wrong and I have checked the code against my book multiple times but could not find any difference.

Comment: std::vector, not vector.

Comment: your include is missing a space as well.

Comment: Oh.That works. My book doesn't have std::. It really baffles me a lot!  Thank you!

Comment: @DanielA.White He doesn't need a space there.

Comment: When you ask questions like this, please also mark the line which encounters the compiler error. (Or just list the program with line numbers)  Do you expect us to count the lines?

Comment: Why is this voted down?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `vector<T>` template class is defined in the `std` namespace. You shouldn't use a `using namespace` statement in a header, so instead you should prefix all STL types with `std::`

```
...
private:
    std::vector<T> pool;
};
...
```

As an aside, assuming this isn't a homework exercise, have you seen `std::stack<T>`? ( http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stack/stack/ )

Comment: Thank you! I didn't know it exits. :)

Answer (score 1):

```
void clear(){
    pool.clear;
}
```

should be

```
void clear(){
    pool.clear();
}
```

And since `vector<T>` is in namespace `std`, you should use

```
std::vector<T> pool;
```

in your class definition.